# Finding the power given the true mean and hypothesis mean

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

A normal distribution is being tested with the hypothesis $H_o: \mu = 0$ and $H_1: \mu>0$. The standard deviation is $3.5$. Calculate the power if the true mean is $11.3\ $?

Attempt

Power =  1 − P(not rejecting a false Ho)

\begin{equation}
Power =  1 − P(not rejecting a false Ho)
\end{equation}

How do I calculate the probability of not rejecting a false $H_o\ $?

Comment: Did you calculate the critical domain ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, to do this I need to calculate the t statistic first for a normal distribution? But to do this I need to know $n$, the sample size?

Comment: The sample size is not given, unfortunately, hence my confusion

Comment: OK, I see. Which $\alpha$ do you use (The probability to make an error of the first kind ?) The power depends on the critical value, and the critical value depends on the choice of $\alpha$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not given either. If I assume an $\alpha$ of 0.05, I can calculate the critical region to be x>= -7.403. How do I then get the power?

Comment: Choose a domain $B$, such that the probability that $X$~$N(0,7/2)$ lies within this domain, has probability at most $0.05$. Then calculate the probability that $Y$~$N(113/10,7/2)$ does NOT lie in this domain. This is the probability to make an error of the second kind.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post because some details were wrong, hope it is correct now.

Comment: Thanks! How would I calculate the critical region if it was a poisson distribution instead?